# change scrollview indicators place in titanium

Tags: android, ios, iphone, scroll, titanium

I'm trying to change the scroll indicator from place. But I don't now if it is possible. What I want to do is for example put the scroll indicator from bottom to top if the scrollview is horizontal or change the indicator from right to left if the scroll is vertical.

Dose someone now if it is possible in titanium studio?

Answer (score 0):

A ScrollView has two properties you an apply to the object. 
`showHorizontalScrollIndicator` which determines if the horizontal scroll indicator is visible and `showVerticalScrollIndicator` which works for the vertical indicator. Both are `false` by default. Set either one to be `true` to display it.

Comment: I already know those object properties. the question is if it is possible to change the vertical scroll indicator from the right side to the left side, or in the vertical scroll from the bottom to the top of the scroll.